# Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AccountSummaryController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am working on angular JS applicaion to make Banking App but I am stuck at a place where my test cases are giving error tht controller not found.
I dont know where I am going wrong any help will be appriciated'

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // CONTROLLERS
    angular
        .module('abcbankApp.controllers', []);

    // SERVICES
    angular
        .module('abcbankApp.services', []);

    angular
        .module('abcbankApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.grid', 'abcbankApp.accountSummary', 'abcbankApp.transaction', 'abcbankApp.login'])
        .config(routeConfig);


    function routeConfig($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
       $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/login");

       $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/login");
        // ROUTES
        // Please use State provoders for routing between login,accountSummary, transactions and search
        // define  $stateProvider(state) with url,templateUrl,controllers and controllerAs
         $stateProvider
          .state("accountSummary", {
            url: "/accountSummary",
            templateUrl: "./templates/account-summary/account-summary.html",
            controller : "AccountSummaryController",
            controllerAs :"ActSumCtrl",
        })
        .state("login", {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "./templates/login/login.view.html",
            controller :"LoginController",
            controllerAs :"LoginCtrl",
        })
}

})();
```

**AccountSummaryController.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
   var appContr = angular.module('abcbankApp.accountSummary', ['abcbankApp.accountSummaryService']);
    appContr.controller('AccountSummaryController', function($scope,AccountSummaryService,$state) {
    var ActSumCtrl = this;
    ActSumCtrl.accountList = [];
    ActSumCtrl.accountList = AccountSummaryService.getAccountSummary();
    });

})();
```

**Acoount service.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

     var appServc = angular.module('abcbankApp.accountSummaryService', []);
appServc.factory('AccountSummaryService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      getAccountSummary: function() {
          var data;
          $http.get('./data/account-summary.json')
         .success(function(response) {
           data = response.data;
        });
        return data;
      }
    };
  }]);

})();
```

But I am getting error like this

```
 Executed 0 of 12 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) abcbankApp.accsummary module AccountSummaryController Controller definition FAILED

    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AccountSummaryController
```

Comment: Why are you creating so many distinct apps? It's going to get very difficult to keep track of your references if every service, controller, etc. is registered in its own AngularJS app. There's really no reason for it unless you intend to use these objects in several different SPAs. Why not create one main app and then simply register your services and controllers directly on that app?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller, the second parameter to an controller is an `array`.

```
appContr.controller('AccountSummaryController', [$scope, function($scope,AccountSummaryService,$state) {
    // code
}]);
```

Comment: It is giving me erro then.Cant compile

Comment: @tyler - Might be you need to inject service too - `appContr.controller('AccountSummaryController', [$scope, AccountSummaryService, $state, function($scope,AccountSummaryService,$state) {
    
}]);`

Comment: THis is also not working .AccountSummaryService is not defined